# Not let UIButton drag outside Circle

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton, drag

I am new to ios.

I have a view in which i had drawn a circle using Quarts core.

I had put one UIButton in that circle and given the Funcnality to DRag and drop that button.

Now i want constraint that the button cant be draged out of that circle area.

The TouchDragOutSide Event of Button is

```
- (void) draggedOut: (UIControl *) c withEvent: (UIEvent *) ev
{
    if([viewCanvas pointInside:[[[ev allTouches] anyObject] locationInView:viewCanvas ] withEvent:ev])
        c.center = [[[ev allTouches] anyObject] locationInView:viewCanvas ];

}
```

At this point the button cant be drag out side of rectangle View area.

Thanks for Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this..

```
if([viewCanvas pointInside:[[[ev allTouches] anyObject] locationInView:viewCanvas ] withEvent:ev])
{
UITouch *touch = [[ev touchesForView:c] anyObject];

CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:c];

if((location.x<(viewCanvas.frame.origin.x+viewCanvas.frame.size.width))&&(location.y<(viewCanvas.frame.origin.y+viewCanvas.frame.size.height)))
{
  c.center = [[[ev allTouches] anyObject] locationInView:viewCanvas ];

}
}
```

Comment: Still it takes rectangle view not taking Circle view

Answer (score 1):

I had make solution by the equation by using this equation.

```
(x-center_x)^2 + (y - center_y)^2 < radius^2
```

Answer (score 0):

you have the  center (x,y) of circle and radius. take the center of the button and check whether it is inside of your x+ radius - width/2 if it moves in x direction and y+ radius - height/2 if it in a y direction. check for the 4 directions and give proper + / -